# What does the nid mean in a java thread dump?

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, jvm, gdb

For example you got a dump like this:

> "MyThread" prio=1 tid=0x0850c9f8 nid=0x1baf runnable

what does the nid mean here? Is it a hex value of pid or lwpid?

Comment: i'm gonna guess it means "native id".  I know next to nothing about GCJ or GDB though.  I just know that Linux threads have pids, and that's the right size for one.

Comment: Your question is answered very thoroughly in this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599608/a-few-questions-about-java-thread-dump.

Comment: seems I got an answer from http://java.sys-con.com/node/1611555. nid Native Identifier of the thread. Indicates LWP id in Solaris. Identifier for this process at the OS level. However in this post http://blogs.manageengine.com/appmanager/2011/02/09/identify-java-code-consuming-high-cpu-in-linux-linking-jvm-thread-and-linux-pid (see step 4) the user use pid to search for the dump and found match, why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it is the native thread ID (that is, the native process ID).

Answer (score 9):

nid is Native Thread ID :
Crucial information as this native Thread Id allows you to correlate for example which Threads from an OS perspective are using the most CPU within your JVM etc.

Comment: Yes, but how do you match them up? The "Thread IDs" I see from my running process (in Windows Process Explorer) don't match the nid in my thread dump. I even converted the hex... no matches.