# understanding line from java thread dump

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, thread-dump, jstack

I have the following thread dump I get using jstack and would like to know what the hex value next to the word `runnable` shows. I have seen the same value used in other places showing as:

```
waiting on condition [0x00000000796e9000]
```

Does this mean the other threads are waiting on this thread?

```
runnable [0x00000000796e9000]
```

thread dump

```
"ajp-bio-8009-exec-2925" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000015ca7000 nid=0x53c7 runnable [0x00000000796e9000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
```

Comment: probably u should ask this in java mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

> I have the following thread dump I get using jstack and would like to
>   know what the hex value next to the word runnable shows. I have seen
>   the same value used in other places showing as:
>
> waiting on condition [0x00000000796e9000]
>
> Does this mean the other threads are waiting on this thread?

Yes. This indicates one thread holds a lock and another thread is waiting to obtain that lock. This is fairly similar to the synchronized keyword conceptually, but can be quite a bit more powerful (and complicated). 
Take a look at the javadoc for [condition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) to get a better understanding of conditions.

This [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599608/how-to-analyze-a-java-thread-dump) gives a description of the attributes in a thread dump (for java 6).