# Explain a thread dump information of Java Hotspot virtual machine

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-dump

Learning and getting a hands on java thread dump I created a thread dump of my IDEA intellij running process. 
The problem is that I don't understand what it means. 
Can you explain what this information means and how to read it ?
No need to list every single detail just the main fields and what each   means and what it indicates as information. 
Here is a small snippet

Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02 mixed mode):

```
"JobScheduler FJ pool 0/4" #165 daemon prio=6 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9cb0001800 nid=0x1d2a waiting on condition [0x00007f9ca7e1e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e74c3c90> (a jsr166e.ForkJoinPool)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinPool.awaitWork(ForkJoinPool.java:1756)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1694)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1642)
    at jsr166e.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:109)
```

and here is the whole [file](https://gist.github.com/AdelinGhanaem/b516fd9d676885fa10a7)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to analyze a java thread dump?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599608/how-to-analyze-a-java-thread-dump)

Answer (score 1):

```
<Name> <nature> <vm priority> <os priority><vm id> <os id> <status [adress]>
```

<[thread state](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html)>

```
 <current execution point>
- detail : wait until timeout or thread 0x00000000e74c3c90 notification
<stack>
```

As far as I understand you have a job scheduler worker thread which has been released to its thread pool (and is waiting for a new job)

See also [How to analyze a java thread dump?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599608/how-to-analyze-a-java-thread-dump)

Comment: Yes this question explains a lot but still want to know how it is done for oracle hotspot